# For wartime conditional Gett, what's the status of intermediary adultery?

Tags: halacha, divorce, arayot

I'm trying to understand the Halachah of David's story with Bat Sheva, relying on the idea of "conditional Gett".

1. a soldier writes a conditional Gett, which states that if he eventually dies, his wife would be considered free from the moment of his departure.
2. while he's away and witnessed alive, his wife is having a witnessed encounter.
3. eventually, he does die either in the war or of something else (she's heartbroken upon hearing the news).

Does it mean that, since he did die, his wife's affairs are automatically nullified aposteriori?

Comment: Yes. That is the point.

Comment: It isn't so simple. See the mishnayos in Gittin, 3rd and 7th perakim (25b, 73a). "מה היא באותן הימים?" - "What is her intermediate status?" Even though ultimately it _turns out_ that she wasn't married, that status was not clarified at the time, and it may very well be that people who guess at it instead of treating it as a safek (doubtful status) are doing a serious aveirah. See there, this applies to many different halachos.

Comment: I think [Gett](https://gett.com/intl/) is a taxi company

Comment: @MichoelR So what's the ruling Halacha?

Comment: @robev I know, I'm trying not to use English words because they look confusing.

Comment: @AlBerko Don't know. It would take some research which I can't do now. I just posted a comment as my knee-jerk reaction: complex question.